# Dungeon! Quick opening strategy for wizard

Tags: dungeon

We have been playing the wizard for some time, but it looks like the wizard has a lot of challenges: The wizard cannot do well unless it makes it to levels 5 or 6. Having said that, one alternative is to blow the secret door on the way to the levels. Otherwise, it has to travel till it reaches a chamber on level 4, and then tele-porting to 5, then level 6.

So both ways typically take a up (on an average) much longer time, then by the time the wizard gathers the treasure, it is usually too late.

What is a quick opening strategy for the wizard which at least lets the wizard start at nearly the same time as the others?

Answer (score 1):

After consulting [this guide](https://howardcc.instructure.com/courses/1079476/pages/analysis-of-playing-levels-in-the-board-game-dungeon) :

How about walking to level 5, and using teleport cards to get back from a level 5 chamber to a relatively close level 4 chamber and then to level 3? I managed to win a game or two like that.